Simple if-block is not entered in published console app - compiler bug?
While debugging an app I came across a behavior that breaks the fundamental principles of program execution flow. I've never seen something like that in 5+ years of C# development.
As you will see below, I'm calling a method that returns true if the user inputs y.
If that's the case, I set another variable to true. Simple, right?
If I run the program in my IDE everything works fine. If I publish the program to a local folder, the behavior breaks. Even though the method returns true, the if-block is not entered.
The problem only occurs if I publish as single, framework dependent file.
I've simplified the problem to a simple console app. Here is the Program.cs:
bool returnedTrue = false;
bool confirmation = GetConfirmation("Should this method return true?");

// this doesn't work
if (confirmation)
{
    returnedTrue = true;
}

// this works:
// returnedTrue = confirmation;

Console.WriteLine("Method returned: " + returnedTrue);
Console.ReadKey();


bool GetConfirmation(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    var timer = 20;

    while (timer != 0)
    {
        var keyAvailable = Console.KeyAvailable;
        if (keyAvailable)
        {
            var keyChar = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Key pressed: " + keyChar + " -> returning " + (keyChar is 'y' or 'Y'));
            return keyChar is 'y' or 'Y';
        }

        Thread.Sleep(250);
        timer--;
    }

    Console.Write(" -> No input: Defaulting to no \n");
    return false;
}

I'm publishing with:
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained true -o ./bin/Release/net8.0/win-x64/publish -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:PublishTrimmed=true

And here is the output:
Should this method return true?
y
Key pressed: y -> returning True
Method returned: False

How is that possible? I have no explanation for this - feel free to try yourself.

The output you show here does not match the code given. Key pressed: y -> returning True in the output but your code would print Key pressed: y -> True, Are you sure you are testing the correct code?

@DavidG Yeah that just was a copy/paste mistake when trying to make the issue more obvious. I corrected it.

I've copied and run your code under the Visual Studio debugger. I get "Method returned: True". So far, so good -- I'll try to publish the way you describe.

Works for me. Can you zip up your entire demo project and make it available, one way or another? I might have done something differently. Which IDE are you using?

@PetterHesselberg Google drive It also contains the run configuration to publish with rider. You could also directly run the compiled exe in bin\Release\net8.0\win-x64\publish or compare it with your build result

That Google drive link doesn't work for me: "We're sorry. You can't access this item because it is in violation of our Terms of Service."

@PetterHesselberg Sorry yeah it has been blocked, probably because it contains an exe file. I requested a review, until then, here is one without the bin folder

Still only getting the expected result. Here are my exact steps, with line breaks all wrong due to this being a comment:
PS D:\git\WhatsUp> dotnet publish
MSBuild version 17.9.8+b34f75857 for .NET
Determining projects to restore...
All projects are up-to-date for restore.
WhatsGoingOn -> D:\git\WhatsUp\bin\Release\net8.0\WhatsGoingOn.dll
WhatsGoingOn -> D:\git\WhatsUp\bin\Release\net8.0\publish
PS D:\git\WhatsUp> .\bin\Release\net8.0\publish\WhatsGoingOn.exe
Should this method return true?
y
Key pressed: y -> returning True
Method returned: True

dotnet --version says 8.0.204, btw

If you are using dotnet publish command, please try the following:
 dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained true -o ./bin/Release/net8.0/win-x64/publish -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:PublishTrimmed=true this will produce the faulty exe
